# A combinatorial card-trick

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

You have $k$ identical decks of cards, with $m$ cards in each deck.

You divide each deck to $l$ packs, $m/l$ cards in each pack.

You arrange the $l$ packs in a row on the table; so that there is a $k\times l$ matrix of packs.

You ask a volunteer-from-audience to pick $k$ packs - one pack from each row.

Then, he looks at his packs and finds out that there is a card which appears in all packs!

How large should $m$ be such that this trick works regardless of what the volunteer picks?

**MY ANSWER**: Here is a method that works with $m=l^k$ cards.

Give each card a unique identifier, which is a vector of $k$ integers in $1,\dots,l$.

In each row $i$, divide the cards to $l$ packs according to the $i$-th element of their identifier.

For example, if $k=2$ and $l=3$, there are 9 cards  {11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33} and the table is:

> Packs in row 1:  {11,12,13} and {21,22,23} and {31,32,33}
>
> Packs in row 2: {11,21,31} and {12,22,32} and {13,23,33}

Suppose the volunteer picks, in row $i$, the $j_i$-th pack. Then, the card with identifier $j_1,\dots,j_k$ appears in every pack. So the trick works.

**MY QUESTIONS**:

- Can this trick work with less than $l^k$ cards?
- What are references for interesting variants of this trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick can't work with less than $l^k$ cards. The volunteer has $l^k$ ways to select packs. Each pair of selections differs in at least one deck. Thus any two selections can't have the same card in common.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any more sophisticated variants of this trick?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: Not that I know of.